# Media Library not displayin thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, migration, thumbnails, media-library

I am rebuilding a site for a client. The site (domain.com) is hosted on SiteGround. I have created a hosting account on my server with same cPanel details (primary domain:domain.com) and I am accessing it using altered HOSTS file.

I re-did the site with dummy content, tried importing posts and media with Wordpress Importer but it gets stuck after 5-10 images.

Tried it for few times, changed PHP version to 7.0, and changed PHP Options to match it (max execution time = 300, max input time = 1000, max upload filesize = 1G... you get it), contacted hosting support...

However, at the end I changed my attitude. Exported tables containing site content from her DB and imported it into my DB. Posts are here, pages too.

Images are in media library but not showing thumbnails (just grayed out placeholder). I can see images when I open a image from media library, go to permalink, click on image link.

I tried regenerating thumbnails (cca 600) but it fixed just 10%. Tried few different plugins, the same.

It fails on the same 90% of images all the time. And if I find a image manually, I can see it.

File permissions are set 755 on all folders inside uploads directory and on all images.

I really dont know what to do. Any solution

Comment: check the error log around the time of the import

Comment: @mike510a  Thanks for the response. I did. Nothing at all.